# Single iteration of part of a function

Tags: java

Heyo y'all. Im trying to separate out part of a function so that it'll only run once. Issue is, I'd like for that part of the function to become available again after a set amount of time. Here's an example of what I have so far.

```
@EventHandler(event = true)
public void Event(getterEvent e) {
    Var1 v1 = e.getData();
    Var2 v2 = e.getData();
    if (v2.hasPermission())
        return;
    if (v1.getData() == Data.Location >= 128.00) {
        if(e.DataValue()){
            - do stuff here -
            }
            e.setCancelled(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Im attempting to limit this part of the function to run once per timed session.

```
if(e.DataValue()){
   - do stuff here -
   }
```

Any input? Thanks!

Comment: What's the question? Create a field that remembers when it was last executed and update it when necessary. Then just have an `if` to check the last run is long ago enough. If this can run on more than one thread, then you might need something like `AtomicLong` or an `AtomicReference` to an `Instant`.

Comment: Your code looks... strange. I assume this is some kind of pseudo code? Results of two successive calls of the same method assigned to variables of different types? And what do you hope to achieve with `v1.getData() == Data.Location >= 128.00`?